# Facebook graph api v2.5: Max limit for /me/friends and /me/likes/?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the max value for the parameter `limit` for `/me/friends/` and `/me/likes`?

I can't find any documentation regarding the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

A general rule of thumb is not to use a limit higher than 100, and use paging to get the next batch. For example, page related maximum limits are 100: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

API calls with a higher limit will take longer, and since you can only get friends who authorized your App too, it is a good idea to keep the limit for `/me/friends` small anyway.

Comment: Why not higher than 100? A single huge request will be faster than multiple small ones. I should keep the limit small because I can only get app-authorized friends? Could you explain because I don't see the link.

Comment: as you can read in my answer, the limit is max 100 for page related endpoints, it is quite possible that facebook implements this max for user related ones too. either way, you can easily test it and see how many objects you get with different limits

Comment: about app-authorized friends: there is no link, not sure what you mean? you can only get friends who authorized your app, so the number is most likely less than 100.

Comment: You're assuming it's bad to specify a limit higher than the maximum limit? I can just specify ?limit=99999 if I wanted to get the most number of records, but I want to know how many I'll actually get. And it's not easy to test because I don't have that many app-authorized friends.

Comment: well, it´s pointless to use a limit that is higher than the maximum. either way, my answer is the only information you can get afaik. if you want to use a limit parameter that is higher than the maximum for whatever reason, that´s totally up to you.